# Does mouseClicked work for JTree?

Tags: java

I am trying to launch an event when clicking a `JTree` node. I use the `MouseListener` functions. It definitely compiles but it does nothing when clicking a node.

Does `MouseListener` work for `JTrees`?

Code:

```
addMouseListener(this);
```

and

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
            singleClick = true;
            timer.start();

        } else {
            singleClick = false;

        }
    }

     private void singleClickHandler(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("-- single click --");
    }

     private void doubleClickHandler(ActionEvent e) throws ParseException {         
        System.out.println("-- double click -- id=");      

    }   


 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
```

Comment: yes, it should work, post your code so we can see why it won't work